# How to detect end of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

i have some problems with my script. So, i want to detect end of my scrolling action. I have my alert when i'm scrolling but not if i'm ending it. Can you help me? This is my code:

```
var animatable = $('body, html');
var animating = false;
animatable.animate( {scrollTop: $('#foo').offset()})

$(window).scroll(function(e) { 
       if(!animating){
           animatable.stop(false, true); 
           alert('stop scrolling');
       }
       animating = false;
});​
```

and some fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhnKR/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Comment: no dude, i don't want to alert at the bottom of my site, but at the end of scrolling action, this is huge different, but thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Event, when User stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

is this what you're trying to achieve:

```
$('body').animate( {scrollTop: $('#foo').offset().top},1000,function(){
 alert('stop scrolling');   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhnKR/2/

You don't have to watch the scroll event if you animate the scroll with jquery.

---

Ok, if you want to detect when the user stopped scrolling, you'll have to use a timeout to check if the user stopped. Otherwise you'll get the event for each scroll step.
Like this:

```
var delay = 1000;
var timeout = null;
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        alert('scrolling stopped');
    },delay);
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhnKR/4/

Comment: no, i need to detect stop of my scrolling action, i'm on the page, i'v started of scrolling and after scroll some space i'v stoped, so i need to detect that moment - when i'm ending it

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski it wasn't clear what exactly you're trying to do from your question and code sample. But i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

maybe adding new events like this:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/

would help