# React notify all children that parent scrolled

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component called Conversation which renders potentially many Parts. I need each Part to know if the Conversation is scrolled. Is this possible, if so how?

```
class Conversation extends Component {
  handleScroll() {
      console.log('Each Part should be told that I just fired');
  }
  render() {
    <div className="conversation" onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)}>
       <Part />
       <Part />
       <Part />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent components should always pass information to sub-components through props e.g.,:

```
<Part someProp={this.getPartProps()} />
```

So figure out what information each `Part` component needs and just provide it.

EDIT:

To propagate that information from your event handler you will need to use component local state:

```
handleScroll: function() {
    this.setState({scrollFired: true});
}
```

Then you can set the props on Part:

```
<Part scrollFired={this.state.scrollFired} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but won't this strategy only work for the first time the parent is scrolled? Imagine the property passed to the Parts is parentScrolling=true. There is no scrollEnded function (as far as I know) so how can I ever set parentScrolling=false so that the Parts will be notified the second and third time the parent is scrolled?

Comment: @TomT what do you want to do in the `<Part/>` component when you scroll?

Comment: Each Part can have a tooltip that is shown when the user hovers over the part. It looks awful when the parent is scrolled, so when the parent is scrolled I want each Part to hide its tooltip.

Comment: In this case you're probably better to use a timeout on the tooltip i.e., wait half a second before showing the tooltip. If the the mouse leaves the `<Part/>` component then cancel the timeout.

Comment: I already do this but scroll is odd in this regard, mouseLeave is not fired for a Part if the mouse leaves that Part because of a scroll. This is why I am trying to react directly to parent scroll.

Comment: I think I can use your original suggestion along with the concept of an artificial scrollEnd event (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320933/how-to-detect-end-of-scrolling). Not sure this is the best solution... but it should work!

Comment: It is a real pain that those mouse events don't fire on scroll. Your artificial scroll end idea seems like the only option.

Comment: Thanks for your help @rojoca, its be great to think/talk this true with someone!