# How to disable click events on mobile devices when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

What's the best method for disabling click events while scrolling / dragging on a mobile device? The problem I have is lets say a user clicks on a button while scrolling down the page on a mobile device. Any effects I have on the buttons gives the impression that the user clicked.

Been looking for a solution for hours, have not found anything that is working. Hoping someone can give me the expert guidance that I am seeking!

Cheers :)

Comment: What have you found so far?

Answer (score 2):

you have to write a condition on button click event using JavaScript or JQuery that if scrolling is enable then button click event are false and for more you have to display your code so i will help you.

Answer (score 2):

*Note : I am using jQuery*

You can use the scrollTop property to track the scrolling of the document.

```
$(".className")[0].ownerDocument.scrollingElement.scrollTop
```

and then used the disabled attribute to disable the button.

```
$("button").attr("disabled","");
```

**Below is the complete code to test how it works.**
Run the snippet.

```js
var pageTopPosition = $(".long-page")[0].ownerDocument.scrollingElement.scrollTop;

setInterval(function() {
  if (pageTopPosition != $(".long-page")[0].ownerDocument.scrollingElement.scrollTop) {
    $("button").attr("disabled", "");
  } else {
    $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  pageTopPosition = $(".long-page")[0].ownerDocument.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
}, 100);
```

```css
.long-page {
  height: 2000px;
}
.popup {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFEFD5;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="long-page">

</div>
<div class="popup">
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```js
var delay = 2000;
var timeout = null;

function doSomethingOnClick(e){
 console.log('clicked');
}

window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};

$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    if(mobilecheck()){
      // to just disable buttons
      //$(':button').prop('disabled', true);
        $(window).off('click');
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('scrolling stopped');
      if(mobilecheck()){
       // Enable all the button
       //$(':button').prop('disabled', false); 
        $(window).on('click', doSomethingOnClick);
        }
    },delay);
});

$(window).on('click', doSomethingOnClick);
```

```css
#foo{
    height: 1200px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top:500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="foo"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Note, the mobilecheck function is taken from here [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)
And scroll end detection from here [How to detect end of scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320933/how-to-detect-end-of-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who commented. I failed with my question and didn't provide enough information / detail that allows users to fully understand what I was asking. Now thinking about it, I should have asked "Is it possible to detect tap and drag on mobile devices?"