# Is there any function "click out" an element div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the value when I stop scrolling a price filter. Is there any event function to do that? I've tried 'mouseout', 'mouseleave', etc...

[image]

Comment: Isn't it a "change" event or something? You don't need to rely on the mouse event.

Comment: @Carcigenicate already but it didn't work

Comment: Show an [mcve] of what you've tried to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Is that an `<input type='range' />`? You don't say. If so `onchange` should work.

Comment: @PHPglue it is <input type='slider' />

Comment: That's not a valid type.

Comment: Questions about input types that don't exist are probably off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a timeout to detect that the user has stopped scrolling, you can refer to this JQuery code:

```
var delay = 1000;
var timeout = null;
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        alert('scrolling stopped');
    },delay);
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Or to that link if you call your event handler directly from HTML (add the timer in the same way) :

[event_onscroll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

Last but not least you can refer to this link:

[how-to-detect-end-of-scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320933/how-to-detect-end-of-scrolling)