# How to add a callback with scrolltop and animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

For IE8 I use this code which uses jQuery to animate a banner at the bottom of the page when the user scrolls to 250 or more.  The problem is that this is extremely slow and has a huge delay, I believe this is because the animate event is firing so many times, I need a callback written in to .stop(); but I'm not sure how/where to put this.  Any ideas?

```
} else {
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 250) {
     if($("#carriage-promo").not(':animated')){
        $("#carriage-promo").animate({
           height: 0
        },100);

     }
  } else {
     if($("#carriage-promo").not(':animated')){
        $("#carriage-promo").animate({
           height: '40px'
        },100);
     }
  }
});
}
```

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling

Comment: Thanks - I had figured this out, but your link is still pretty handy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 250) {
     if($("#carriage-promo").not(':animated')){
        $("#carriage-promo").stop(true,true).animate({
           height: 0
        },100);

     }
  } else {
     if($("#carriage-promo").not(':animated')){
        $("#carriage-promo").stop(true,true).animate({
           height: '40px'
        },100);
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, trying now!

I'm assuming this just stops the animation before firing it again?

Comment: Correct! and removes pending animations from quee too

Comment: This does seem slightly better, and I can't see any queued animations, but it's still nothing like as fast/smooth as the CSS3 version I have for supporting browsers. :/   I can't figure out what could possibly slowing this down.  Any more ideas?

EDIT:  Played around with it a bit, and it's pretty much perfect now!  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ended up using true, false as true,true wasn't allowing the animation to finish before showing the banner.  Thanks again! :)