# hide jquery datepicker while scrolling

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

How to hide JQuery date picker while scrolling the page?
Already I tried with this code

```
.datepicker._pos[1] += input.offsetHeight + document.body.scrollTop;
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Get the Id of the input field.

```
eg.  var txtestimatestartdate = $('#txtestimatestartdate').datepicker();
```

Use this below code

```
 $("#Scroll").scroll(function () {
    txtestimatestartdate.datepicker('hide');
    $('#txtestimatestartdate').blur();             
});
```

Where '#Scroll' is the Id for the div which you have applied scrolling. This will automatically hide the datepicker while scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618549/1387161)

Just when you are scrolling to `.datepicker.hide();`

And show it back when done `scrolling.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scroll demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: blue;
  }
  p {
    color: green;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
    display: none;
  }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<div>Try scrolling the iframe.</div>

<p>Paragraph - <span>Scroll happened!</span></p>

<script>

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('hide');
  $( "span" ).css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo link here http://jsbin.com/ahEYeWe/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the jQuery UI datepicker?

If so I've done a jsfiddle for you below. Here I have made it so that when scrolling the datepicker disappears, but also I have done it so that the focus leaves the input.

I have done this so than when you scroll back up to the input field and you click on it again the datepicker will re-appear as this wouldn't happen if the input field still had focus from the previous click.

http://jsfiddle.net/4yaMd/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $(window).bind('scroll',function () {
       $('#datepicker').blur();
       $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();              
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery's `scroll` event handler, like so

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 $('.datepicker').hide().fadeIn(800);
}
```

As the example on http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ (right at the bottom) seems to point out.

Edit:

And it works. http://jsfiddle.net/x3s7F/.