# detect when page is being scrolled

Tags: jquery, scroll

What I want: 
- I want to detect when a user is scrolling the page. Not once, but every single time.
- When user stopped scrolling, something must happen.

What I DONT want:
detect when the page is scrolled to a certain point(so **no** waypoints.js).

A solution that I've tried at first:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log("page scrolled");
});
```

Problem is, he fires the console.log way too many times. So maybe I need some sort of delay, but I don't know how to fix that properly.

Hope someone of you can help!

Comment: Are you talking about something like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/24M3n/1/)**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution to fire alert when page stop scrolling.

**code**

```
var timer;
$(window).on('scroll',function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout( scrollStop , 150 );
});
var scrollStop = function () { 
    // do stuff
    alert('Scrolling Stop'); 
};
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vj745/2/)

Reference [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling/12618549#12618549)