# How to detect page scrolling stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert when user stop scrolling the page.

Below code show logs when page scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log('page scrolling');
});
```

but can we show log when page stop scrolling.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12618549/1117720

Comment: You can probably use this jquery plugin https://github.com/ssorallen/jquery-scrollstop

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Event, when User stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Comment: Here you have a similar (or same) question with a few answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling