# Make navbar return into focus if user stops scrolling for more than 1s

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently my code snippet hides the navbar as the user scrolls down and brings it back into view as the user scrolls up.

How would I also bring it back into view once the user stops scrolling down (or pauses momentarily)?

**Code:**

```
var mywindow = $(window);
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
var up = false;
var newscroll;
mywindow.scroll(function () {
    newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
    if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
        $('.header').stop().slideToggle();
        up = !up;
        console.log(up);
    } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
        $('.header').stop().slideToggle();
        up = !up;
    }
    mypos = newscroll;
});
```

**Jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GM46N/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you'd want to use a setTimeout at the end of your scroll event and clear it as soon as the event is fired again, as in:

```
var mywindow = $(window);
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop(); 
var up = false;
var newscroll;
mywindow.scroll(function () {
newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
clearTimeout(a);
if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
    $('.header').stop().slideToggle();
    up = !up;
    console.log(up);
} else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
    $('.header').stop().slideToggle();
    up = !up;
}
var a = setTimeout(function(){
if (up) {
    $('.header').stop().slideToggle();
    up = !up;
} 
},1400);
mypos = newscroll;
});
```

I hope this helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You need a timeout.

Since it looks like your using jQuery here is a resource with a bunch of examples for timeout solutions regarding scrolling event: [jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling)