# jquery on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make it so a img changes to a gif when the user is scrolling on a site.

**HTML**

```
<img src="img/giphy.gif" alt="" id="imgAnimate">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#imgAnimate").hover(
                function()
                {
                    $(this).attr("src", "img/giphy.gif");
                },
                function()
                {
                    $(this).attr("src", "img/giphy.png");
                });
        });
```

I got this but now is it when you hover over the img it changes into a gif.
How can I make this happen when user is scrolling.

Thanks you if you can help me.

Comment: Use `$(window).scroll` instead of `$("#imgAnimate").hover`.

Comment: @Mohammad no that is not working

Comment: Do you mean when user scroll to the image itself or scroll in general ?

Comment: when the user scrolls with his mouse wheel the image needs to change to the gif and when he stops scrolling again the gif needs to change back to the image

Comment: @Mohammad if I use the .scroll there it doesnt know where to place the images

Comment: "hover" includes mousehover and mouseout  events on your image. so when you mousehover you show gif img and when you mouseout you show jpg or png image. but when you say I want it on scroll which means once you scrolls your image will be converted to gif , but it will not go back to jpg or png image.

Comment: so now you have to decide if you really want scroll function to work. then you must check if there is anything like scroll up and scroll down. so that on scroll down you can show gif and on scroll up show jpg or png image. And one more thing check when you want your function to work on window scroll or image container scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/q6Lun0dj/1/

use this script :

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    var scrollNow = false;
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
      if(!scrollNow){
        scrollNow = true;
        $("#imgAnimate").attr("src", "http://bart.aoweb.nl/template%205/img/giphy.gif");
      }
      clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
      $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
        scrollNow = false;
        $("#imgAnimate").attr("src", "http://bart.aoweb.nl/template%205/img/giphy.png");
      }, 250) );

    });

  });

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: It is not fully working like I want it to here is a link http://bart.aoweb.nl/template%205/ This is what I am working on I want the character to move smooth but when you scrolling now it is kinda wierd you know a way to fix it?

Comment: Ok, i updated the answer and I hope that is what you want , also see fiddle with your real example here https://jsfiddle.net/5rharr4h/

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll, you can use this code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $( window ).scroll(function(){
                $(this).attr("src", "img/giphy.gif");
            });
    });
```

when you stop scrolling you can 
[Event when user stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/event-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Comment: I tried that code but the gif is already moving when I am not scrolling or do I need to change something in my HTML aswel?

Comment: I gues that could work but with that code it doesnt know where to place the gif I gues

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're checking if the image is being hovered and only then changing it's source. Instead attach a `scroll` event listener to the `document`.

```
$(document).on('scroll', callback);
```