# Custom Scrolling in Js & jQuery : One scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm currently listening for scrollevents in jQuery, using the following code:

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {

   var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;

   if (delta > 0) //do something
   else //do something else
});
```

The issue I'm having is that when the user scrolls, lots of `wheel` events are fired.

I want each time the user scrolls to only process the first scroll event.

I.E.:  I only want to process the first `wheel` event and then stop listening/processing them until the user stops scrolling. At this point I want to start listening again so I can handle the next scroll.

I've seen `mousewheel DOMMouseScroll` used rather than `.on('wheel')` but don't know enough about the differences to know if that could help.

Cheers,
James

Comment: Those other events will have the same issue - the wheel events fire once for each increment scrolled. The scrollwheel movement is not treated as a single event, but as a series of them - similar to how a traditional scroll event is fired once per pixel moved, instead of as a single movement of X pixels.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/event-when-user-stops-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin to rate limit your function. The following code will limit the callback to executing once every 250ms.

```
  $(window).scroll($.debounce(250, true, function(){
    console.log('Scrolling!');
  }));
```

It's also possible to use the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) libraries as they also have a debounce function.

Comment: Works fantastically. Debounce looks like a very useful plugin too. Thanks!