# Sticky nav active state working on click instead of on scroll

Tags: css, scroll, nav, sticky, box-shadow

I have a navigation bar at the top of the page and I'm trying to get a box shadow to appear underneath it on scroll.

I've tried using .active and :active with no luck. I can force the shadow to appear in chrome devtools but can't get this to work otherwise on scroll.

```
.sidenav-breadcrumbs {
    height: 45px; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: red;
}
.nav-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
}
.shadow:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)!important;
}
```

Shadow should appear under bar on scroll but seems to only appear when clicking the bar.
Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Please post html code.

Comment: `:active` is a state that we can use for `<a>` or `<button>` tag, not for a navbar! When you scroll, try to add an additional class using Javascript to the navbar and in that additional class declare the box-shadow property. Its simple!

Comment: <div class="sidenav-breadcrumbs nav-fixed-top shadow">
  </div>

Comment: Thank you @Shuvo, you pointed me in the right direction. I used this code and all working well:

$(window).scroll(function() {     
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 0) {
      $(".sidenav-breadcrumbs").addClass("active");
  }
  else {
      $(".sidenav-breadcrumbs").removeClass("active");
  }
});

Comment: Happy to help @ryannewell

Answer (score 0):

[Active selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) applies to clicked element, that's why the shadow appears when you click the bar. There is no selector for scroll, so you should be using JavaScript to add the `shadow` class while scrolling.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    addShadowClassToBar();
});
```

And since you probably want to remove the shadow after scrolling is finished you should also remove the class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/event-when-user-stops-scrolling) is a previous question that deals with detecting scroll stop.